# cannot install pcap in python 3 in window

Tags: pcap

working in a enclosed environment:
download pcapy-0.11.1.tar.gz and pypcap-1.1.3.tar.gz

### building using 'python setup.py install'

building 'pcapy' extension Error: unable to find vcvarsall.bat
building 'pypcap' File "setup.py",line 40, print "Found pcap header in %s" %pcap_h

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817869/error-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat

Comment: Possible duplicate of [error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817869/error-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat)